# Setting Tab Order Visually in Many Tabs

Tags: .net, vb.net, tabs, key

VB2010: I am very familiar with setting the tab order in my controls on my form using the visual aid under View>Tab Order. I love this visual feature. One thing I am having trouble with and haven't figured out how to do is, say I have a Tab control with 3 tabs. Each tab has numerous controls like textboxes, radio buttons, and buttons. Using the visual tool how do I cycle from Tab1 to Tab2 to Tab3 to set the order of my control tabbing within each tab?

Sorry for the multi-defintion of "tab". Here I am talking about both the Tab control with multiple panels and tab as in the tab key to skip from control to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't ever used the visual aid you are mentioning but haven't ever had any problem to set up the tab ordering by affecting the `TabIndex` property of all the controls in a given (control-)container, both via "Design View" and programatically.

In your specific example, you should go `Tab` by `Tab` and modify the `TabIndex` of each control in it: start from the one you want to be first, assign the start index to it, and keep going one by one by increasing the `TabIndex` value. Bear in mind that there is no absolute start/end; the default behaviour is starting from zero but you can start from any number.

NOTE: I have tested the "Tab Order" functionality now and you can make it work by selecting the given Tab (as you would be doing in my suggestion above): quit "Tab Order mode" (go as usual when you want to deal with the Controls through Design View), select the Tab you want and enable Tab Order; once you are done with the given Tab disable Tab Order (= go back to the normal mode), then select a new Tab, enable Tab Order again, etc. Thus, you have to select the given container (in this case, a Tab) before entering in "Tab Order Mode".